# Which one is good practice to do something like 'out' from C# in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript

Since I met the [`out` keyword in C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier), I'm trying to find an equivalent approach in JS.

##### So, please take a look at the code and leave your opinions of existing cases or suggestions of new ways to implement this.

The working version is inside this sandbox:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-out

1 null on fail

```js
const number_1 = tryParseNullOnFail(numberAsString);

if (null !== number_1) {
  page.log(`#1 Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_1}`);
} else {
  page.log(`Failed to convert '${numberAsString}'`);
}
```

2 kvp response

```js
const { isNumber: isNumber_2, number: number_2 } = tryParseKvp(numberAsString);

if (isNumber_2) {
  page.log(`#2 Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_2}`);
} else {
  page.log(`Failed to convert '${numberAsString}'`);
}
```

3 by reference

```js
const number_3 = [];

if (tryParseByReference(numberAsString, number_3)) {
  page.log(`#3 Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_3[0]}`);
} else {
  page.log(`Failed to convert '${numberAsString}'`);
}
```

4 condition expression

```js
if (null != (number_4 = tryParseCondExp(numberAsString))) {
  page.log(`#4 Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_1}`);
} else {
  page.log(`Failed to convert '${numberAsString}'`);
}
```

5 IIFE short cercuit

```js
const number_5 =
  tryParseNullOnFail(numberAsString) ??
  (() => {
    page.log(`Failed to convert '${numberAsString}'`);
  })();

page.log(`#5 Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_5}`);
```

6 high order function

```js
function withTryParse(str, onSuccess, onFail) {
  const number = Number(str);
  isNumber(number) ? onSuccess(number) : onFail(str);
}

const onSuccess = (number_6) => {
  page.log(`#6 Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_6}`);
};

const onFail = (str) => {
  page.log(`Failed to convert '${str}'`);
};

withTryParse(numberAsString, onSuccess, onFail);
```

The mad professor

```js
for (
  var done = false, number_ = tryParseMad(numberAsString);
  !done && null !== number_;
  done = true
) {
  page.log(`#* Converted '${numberAsString}' to ${number_}`);
}
```

Comment: [How best to implement out params in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3175687)  Personally, it looks like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, that's a good article that I found earlier but it does not try a different approach but by reference. I'm trying to find there may be something that I've missed.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better venue for your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm actually pretty sure this person posted a similar question at code review.

Comment: Yeah, it was closed just recently: [C# 'out' keyword in JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268878/47364).

Comment: Seems like you got satisfactory answers at Code Review.  What more were you expecting here?

Comment: _In this particular case_, parsing a string to a number, returning **NaN** is a very natural way to express failure.  In the more general case, most JS code either returns null on failure, or what you call a KVP: your options 1 or 2.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your goal is. The `out` parameter modifier in C# does two things: 1) It makes the parameter pass-by-reference instead of the default pass-by-value. 2) It makes the callee responsible for definitely assigning the reference. #1 is impossible in ECMAScript, since ECMAScript is always pass-by-value. It would require changing the language specification. #2 is a check that is performed by the language, so again, it can only be added by changing the language specification. (You might be able to implement something like that in an ESLint plugin, though.)

Comment: So, whichever way you put it "doing something like `out` from C# in JavaScript" requires adding something like `out` from C# to the JavaScript language, at which point the language is no longer JavaScript, so you are not actually "doing something like `out` from C# in JavaScript" anymore, you are "doing something like `out` from C# in a language that is not JavaScript but somewhat related". Adding #2 to JavaScript is probably possible, since something similar is already specified for `const`. Adding #1 is going to be a lot more work, since pass-by-reference does not exist at all at the moment.

Comment: Yes indeed I've posted to codereview but they said to get here :D Well, I'm expecting to have different opinions from different people. And maybe there will be some particular person who may show another way to solve this, that may be interesting and good to research.

Answer (score 1):

`out` parameters in C# are one way of implementing the "try get pattern", where we may receive either nothing, or a value. So `bool TryGetXxx<T>(out T value)` is a common way that that pattern is implemented in C#.

But for any language that offers discriminated unions, the `Maybe<T>` type can be used instead. It either returns `none` or a value. So if you can use TypeScript rather than JavaScript, [then this StackOverflow answer summarises various ways this type can be created and used in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50574018/7122).

If you can't use TypeScipt, then a common way of implementing a "poor man's maybe type" is via using `null` to represent `none`, as per your "null on fail" option. Of course, this only works in situations where `null` isn't a valid return value, but if it isn't this is a simple and effective solution to your requirement.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. That's why I put `nullOnFail` first because it's the first thought that you have when getting into a similar case. But that implies you have to do double `if`. What are you thinking about #2?